# Is there any good alternative for python's webkit module that works on windows?

Tags: python

Is there any official good alternative for webkit that works on windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try QtWebKit module from [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro).